# Windows ASM printf with float

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, x86-64, calling-convention

I have been trying to interface with the standard C library in Windows in assembler and I'm having trouble. For some reason, I can't make printf accept floating point variables, so something is wrong here.

This is the shortest program I can create that demonstrates the problem. I've included comments that explain my understanding of what is supposed to be happening.

Thanks

```
;
; Hello64.asm
; A simple program to print a floating point number in windows
;
; assemble: nasm float64.asm -f win64
; link: golink /console /entry main float64.obj MSVCRT.dll
;

; tell assembler to generate 64-bit code
;
bits 64

; data segment
section .data use64

pi  dq 3.14159

textformat: db "hello, %lf!",0x0a, 0x00     ; friendly greeting

; set up the .text segment for the code
section .text use64

; global main is the entry point
global main
; note that there is no _ before printf here, unlike in OS X
extern printf

main:
mov rcx, textformat 
movq xmm0, qword [pi]
mov rax, 1      ; need to tell printf how many floats
call printf

; note next step - this puts a zero in rax
xor rax,rax
ret ; this returns to the OS based on how Windows calls programs.
; this return causes a delay then the program exits.
```

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but what does `osx` have to do with this?

Comment: Sorry - that comment was for me. In OS X with NASM you need to put a _ in front of the names of the clib function names so the linker will link them correctly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `printf` requires the runtime to have been initialized, and you aren't doing that.

Comment: @RaymondChen, how would you initialize the runtime? The code provided by Jester works as written, and I've done "hello world" with text without any additional steps to initialise the runtime.

Comment: You let the runtime control the executable entry point. It will initialize itself, then call `main`, and then when `main` returns, it will flush the output buffers and do other cleanup activities before exiting the process.

Comment: Oh yeah, well spotted, @Raymond.  His linker command sets the entry point to `main`, rather than letting the CRT startup code call `main`.  On Linux if you want to write a "bare" executable, you just write `_start` instead of `main`.  glibc stuff like printf and malloc do work even without the crt startup code, at least in the tiny amount of testing I've done.

Comment: I just tested this - golink assumes "Start" as the startup point.

The executable where I specify the main entry point is 982 bytes long, but the executable where I use the default entry point as described is 1055 bytes long. The additional code is pretty small. I'll keep that in mind when creating more complex programs. Thanks for the information!

Comment: It should be noted that the use of `msvcrt.dll` by third-party applications is not officially supported by Microsoft.  This doesn't seem to matter too much in practice - I only recall ever coming across one question in which I thought this was actually likely to be the problem - but FYI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You managed to mix the microsoft and the sysv convention. The correct way is:

```
mov rcx, textformat 
movq xmm1, qword [pi]
movq rdx, xmm1  ; duplicate into the integer register
sub rsp, 40     ; allocate shadow space and alignment (32+8)
call printf
add rsp, 40     ; restore stack
xor eax, eax
ret
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd2wa36c.aspx), when using varargs:

> For floating-point values only, both the integer and the floating-point register will contain the float value in case the callee expects the value in the integer registers.

Comment: That did it! I did not know that you had to duplicate it into the corresponding regular register (in the parameter passing order).

Also, why is the stack alignment 40? I understand the 32 for the "home" space for the four standard parameters, but why the additional 8 bytes (64 bits)?

Comment: Huh, that's a weird ABI design. I had no idea the Windows calling convention did that.  @querist: It's only [varargs functions that need float args duplicated in the corresponding integer reg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd2wa36c.aspx).  The additional 8B is so the stack will be 16B-aligned after `call` pushes a return address.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterCordes.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's so that the called function can spill its parameters easily.

Comment: @RaymondChen: That's the 32B "home"/"shadow" space.  Querist was asking about the 8 bytes beyond that.  BTW, now that I think about it, passing fp args in both places simplifies implementing C vararg macros a LOT.  It can always just store all four integer parameter regs into the shadow space like normal, and then the args form a linear array with no gaps.  I assume that's the main point of the shadow space.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I was answering the question "Why are floating point varargs duplicated into integer registers?"