# Linux and Windows x86 assembly calling conventions

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, x86, nasm

From what I've been able to find, between Linux and Windows there are two common calling conventions: arguments for function calls are loaded either into registers or placed on the stack.

For example with the `printf` function it is said Linux loads registers with the arguments that `printf` needs. For `printf` on Windows I've seen both conventions used. In my class, they have us place the arguments on the stack, however in code examples online the arguments are placed in registers.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351451/printf-arguments-not-pushed-on-the-stack) by Basile Starynkevitch, made me think Windows used stack only for arguments and Linux used registers.   [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943615/windows-asm-printf-with-float) by Jester shows Windows using registers for `printf` arguments.

Next small part of the code I've written for my class shows that on Windows I've been using the stack for arguments:

```
section .data
msg:  db "my message", 0ah, 0

section .text
_main:
        
    push   msg
    call   _printf
    add    esp, 4
```

- So is Windows capable of using both calling conventions?
- And how do you know which should be used?
- Is it different for 32-bit and 64-bit x86 programs?

I've also seen that people are able to use `printf` in Windows assembly without the underscore. I know that is normal for Linux assembly code but on Windows I get an error if I don't use the underscore. Others on Windows don't seem to have this problem.

In the original question that Jester answers (link above), it doesn't seem as though the user asking the question uses any special NASM instruction that would allow for that, unless it is something in the linker command they're using.
C. K. Young only [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028454/how-to-resolve-the-symbol-of-printf-instead-of-printf-on-win32-console) how you can use `printf` without an underscore if you use a certain NASM option.

- So why can some Windows assembly programs use `printf` without the underscore when they aren't using the NASM option?

I've searched quite a bit but haven't found any explanations for these strange cases.

Comment: Calling convention differs between 32 and 64 bit, yes.  And the symbol decoration (presence of leading underscore) differs, too.  Make sure not to mix these up.

Comment: https://agner.org/optimize/ has a calling-convention guide that covers the differences between Windows / non-Windows and 32 vs. 64-bit x86.

Comment: the ABI also treats functions without prototypes or with a variable number of them (like printf) differently, and doesn't only change by OS but also the CPU type, as well as being configurable, depending on the language used. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/calling-conventions) for the calling conventions of the specific configuration you are interested should be consulted for details.

Comment: Expanding on [@fuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuz) comment, I think that "Calling Convention" is not used properly in you question and might be a part of why you are getting confusing search results. "printf vs _printf" identify the different names that function can have when exported, while it is common in Windows to have "cdecl calling convention" functions use a leading underscore in their name, it is only a convention and to know for sure how it expects its parameters you should check the header and documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32-bit x86 CPUs don't have that many registers to use, so most calling conventions originally designed for them use mainly the stack.

This is obviously not as fast as using registers, and therefore once 64-bit x86 CPUs became more common, parameters were stored in registers as much as possible.

To produce a fully working application, you need to link your code to a "libc"; Windows provides at least 2 of those with their SDK, and there are also independent implementations like the one used by MinGW-w64; each of them will have their functions exported using a specific calling convention that you should match, and using leading "_" in the name is usually how it prevents conflicting calls from linking successfully.

Comment: Thank you Carlo and everyone for the clarification and documentation. also thank you Sep for the grammar fixes.